# How do I determine what kind of fundamental interaction is responsible for a certain reaction?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, standard-model

can somebody explain to me how to determine - from the given chemical equation - what kind of interaction is responsible for a certain kind of process?

Examples:

1. $e^+ + e^-\to\tau^+ + \tau^-$
2. $K^+\to\pi^+ + \pi^0 + \gamma$
3. $\phi(s\bar{s})\to K^+ + K^-$
4. $\eta\to 3\pi^0$
5. $K^+\to\mu^+ + \nu_\mu$
6. $\Sigma^+\to p + \pi^0$
7. $\Lambda + p\to K^- + p + p$
8. $D^-\to K^+ + \pi^- + \pi^-$

(This is a former exam question in nuclear/particle physics.)

What we thought initially was that 1) is electro-magnetic interaction (em) because $e^+$ and $e^-$ annihilate to become a photon before "splitting" again and creating a new pair. But some search on google has indicated that for tauons to be created, there has to be very high energy available and for high energies, $e^- e^+$ *can* annihilate into a Z-boson. Therefore our best guess is now weak force.

2. Kaons contain strange or antistrange quarks, pions and gammas do not, therefore 2) should be weak force. Potentially also electromagnetic force because of the $\gamma$. --> If a photon goes into or comes out of a feynman diagram, is it always an electromagnetic interaction?
3. We covered this in a lecture thankfully, $s$ and $\bar{s}$ become $K^+$ and $K^-$ by exchanging a gluon which indicates strong force.

Generally we seem to have established that when a quark-antiquark-pair is created, it is always due to a gluon being exchanged. Is that correct?

4. $\eta$ contains strange quarks, $\pi$ doesn't, therefore again weak force.
5. A meson changes into an antilepton and lepton-neutrino --> weak force.
6. $\Sigma^+$ has a $s$-quark, neither proton nor pion do, therefore weak force.
7. $uds + uud\to s\bar{u} + uud + uud$ so a $u\bar{u}$ pair is created --> strong force.
8. $d\bar{c}\to \bar{s}u + d\bar{u} + d\bar{u}$ so particles other than ($q\bar{q}$)-pairs are being created --> weak force.

Did I get it right? Are there any rules I didn't mention?

Another question was "Which forces act on the following particles: gluon, neutron, neutrino, quark, W-boson, $K^+$?" There we would answer "All" in the case of quark, neutron and $K^+$, "weak and em" in the case of W-boson, "strong" for gluons and "weak" for neutrinos.

Also could you confirm or correct the following statement: Whenever there is a neutrino --> weak force. Whenever there is weak force --> neutrino."

Comment: There are no chemical equations in particle physics. To guide in the allowed reactions one should use the standard model  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model , and it is very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The exam tests how well you understand the PDG. Strong and EM interactions conserve flavor, but weak ones  need not.

1. Your first guess is right, and your revised one wrong. Look at the order of magnitude of the masses of the *τ*s, so the EM reaction can go at energies much-much tinier than the Z pole (how much)? Of course, when you are right-smack on that pole, at 91GeV, the weak reaction  will be large.
2. Yes, both.  A photon is the hallmark of EM.
3. Yes. Did you check its width on the PDG? Remember your rule in the next question!
4. It contains a strange and an anti strange quark(-antiquark) so you forgot your rule from above? How could a weak interaction be comparable in size to the EM (anomalous) dominant one? Approximate rules of the strong interactions are violated, which accounts for the suppression pulling the strong interaction to an EM scale, but surely you can draw a strong diagram, schematically...
5. Obviously yes.
6. Ditto. Most sane people use Σ.
7. Use Λ . Yes.
8. Yes.

Your basic rule of following the quarks and their flavors is a sound one.

> Whenever there is a neutrino --> weak force.

Yes.

> Whenever there is weak force --> neutrino.

No. The intermediate W may well only couple to quarks: did you forget your 6.?

> Another question was "Which forces act on the following particles: gluon, neutron, neutrino, quark, W-boson, +?" There we would answer "All" in the case of quark, neutron and +,"weak and em" in the case of W-boson, "strong" for gluons and "weak" for neutrinos.

Yes. It's not in your book, or WP?